# Automatic login does not work on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, mobile-web

I quite like the new mobile site but if I switch to another SE site it doesn't automatically log me in. On the desktop site it does.

Is this a bug?

---

My platform is iOS 4.3.3 on an iPod touch. Browser is Mobile Safari. Yes, JavaScript is enabled and the page fully loads and the debug console is empty (no errors).

Comment: it will if you go to the login page, though. But I agree this might be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With our next deploy global login will be enabled on the mobile site.

We're still tweaking the styling of the popup, but *functionally* we should be OK.

Comment: automatic login is still not implemented?