# Should I delete my question that was closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, bug, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete)

So, I have asked a question, that was a bug, that was a duplicate here on the meta a week or so back.  It was closed as a duplicate which it should have been I didn't see the previous post.

My question is should I delete that question because it is localized to a fixed bug or should I leave it behind?

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98483/163737) is the question I asked and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98286/163737) is the question that it was a duplicate of, just for reference.

Comment: No you shouldn't, nor should you delete this duplicate :)